# Defining a Datasource

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

Usually we define a datasource like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:."/>
<property name="username" value="sa"/>
<property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

However, how to define a "dataSource" pointing to a NoSQL database like Appengine Datastore?

The idea is to allow the "dataSource" to be passed into a bean that is used for Spring security:

```
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref=”dataSource” />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Comment: it's javax.sql.DataSource - note the SQL in the package name.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security requires a JDBC data source. Yiou would need to get a JDBC driver for your NoSQL database. AFAIK, Google App Engine Datastore doesn come with a JDBC driver, but there were some attempts to write one, so you can give it a shot.